# Receiving only modified fields in ZF2

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, extjs4

### Front End

Ext Js 4.2

The config of Ext.data.writer.Writer, writeAllFields when set false only send the fields that were modified.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Writer-cfg-writeAllFields

### Back End

Zend Framework 2.2

```
class SomeForm extends Zend\Form\Form {

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array()) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'field_foo',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'field_bar',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        ));        
    }
}

class SomeFormFilter extends Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter {

    public function __construct() {    
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'required' => false
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'field_foo',
            'required' => true
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'field_bar',
            'required' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

In the service layer we check if the data sent is valid

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Form.Form.html#isValid

```
$form->isValid()
```

When back end receives

1. Modified all fields: Request Method: PUT Form Data:
   {"field_foo":"value string","field_bar":"value string", "id":"22"} 
   That's right.field_foo and field_bar are required and return true.
2. Modified only, field_foo: Request Method: PUT Form Data:
       {"field_foo":"value string","id":"22"}  isValid() return false
       because field_bar is required.

Which way to the solution?

Remove field?
http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Form.Form.html#remove

Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating only the fields that are interested. In this case, only the fields sent in the request.

```
public function foo($rawData) // array('id' => 1, 'field_foo' => 'value')
{ 
    $form = $this->getForm(); // @var Zend\Form\Form

    $group = array_keys($rawData); // array(0 => 'id', 1 => 'field_foo')
    $form->setValidationGroup($group);

    $form->setData($rawData); // array('id' => 1, 'field_foo' => 'value')

    $isValid = $form->isValid();

    // some code       
}
```

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups

Answer (score 0):

Provide a different inputFilter for update operations

or

set `writeAllFields` to `true` and send and save all values